# Can I update a mongo document from inside a cursor traversal function?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to update a mongo doc from inside a cursor traversal function (similar to mongoose)?

Something like:

```
db.collection.find({email:"xxx@test.com"}).forEach(doc => {
  doc.newProp = 'newValue';
  doc.save();
});
```

Comment: We can do aggregation followed by `$out` to same collection turning it to an update operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with below query, It should solve your issue:-

```
db.collection.find({email:"xxx@test.com"}).forEach(doc => {
db.collection.update({_id: doc._id},{$set:{"newProp":"value"}});
});
```

**$set** will update the existing value,Otherwise It will add new  field with the given value if it not present in the document.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was already solved (see my own answer below) but your solution is more accurate than mine. Marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

looks like it can be done this way:

```
db.collection.find({email:"xxx@test.com"}).forEach(doc => {
  doc.newProp = 'newValue';
  db.collection.save(doc);
});
```