# mongodb: updating an object inside array using forEach

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a collection called *vehicles* whose structure is given below.

```
[
   {
      "vehicleType":"car",
      "parts":[
         {
            "partName":"engine",
            "buyingPrice":145.00,
            "sellingPrice":200.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"brake",
            "buyingPrice":50.00,
            "sellingPrice":70.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"wheel",
            "buyingPrice":70.00,
            "sellingPrice":75.00
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "vehicleType":"bike",
      "parts":[
         {
            "partName":"engine",
            "buyingPrice":1450.00,
            "sellingPrice":2000.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"brake",
            "buyingPrice":507.00,
            "sellingPrice":170.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"wheel",
            "buyingPrice":70.00,
            "sellingPrice":75.00
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "vehicleType":"car",
      "parts":[
         {
            "partName":"engine",
            "buyingPrice":1450.00,
            "sellingPrice":2000.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"brake",
            "buyingPrice":50.00,
            "sellingPrice":170.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"wheel",
            "buyingPrice":700.00,
            "sellingPrice":750.00
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to update the sellingPrice as 500.00 if the partName is *brake* and sellingPrice is <= 170.00. I excuted the below query, but it is updating the value only for the 1st object.

```
db.getCollection("vehicles").find({})
.forEach(function(v){
   v.parts.forEach(function(p){
      if(p.partName=="brake" && p.sellingPrice<=170.00){
         p.sellingPrice=500.00;
         print(v);
      }
   })
})
```

Below is the output of above query

```
[
   {
      "vehicleType":"bike",
      "parts":[
         {
            "partName":"engine",
            "buyingPrice":1450.00,
            "sellingPrice":2000.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"brake",
            "buyingPrice":507.00,
            "sellingPrice":500.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"wheel",
            "buyingPrice":70.00,
            "sellingPrice":75.00
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "vehicleType":"car",
      "parts":[
         {
            "partName":"engine",
            "buyingPrice":1450.00,
            "sellingPrice":2000.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"brake",
            "buyingPrice":50.00,
            "sellingPrice":170.00
         },
         {
            "partName":"wheel",
            "buyingPrice":700.00,
            "sellingPrice":750.00
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Don't know what went wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to do that is with the following query using the [positional operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) `$`

```js
db.getCollection('vehicles').updateMany({
  "parts.partName": "brake",
  "parts.sellingPrice": {
    $lte: 170.00
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "parts.$.sellingPrice": 500
  }
})
```

In case you can use mongodb cursor methods like `forEach` try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49612019/16067905).

Comment: The query which i provided above is executing, but it is updating values only to the first filtered object. I need to update for all the filtered datas.